# how to add header in Api Management soap pass through URL?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, wsdl, azure-api-management

I am using Azure API Management Soap Pass through URL(ENdpoint)
It has subscription key for authentication.

But when I add wsdl web endpoint have only base address and not header. And after web service call I am getting the error:

> {"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
>    The authentication header received from the server was 'Key realm=\"https:\url\",name=\"Key\",type=\"header\"'."}

I guess I am missing passing a header.

How to pass header to call web api endpoint?
We cant mention it in web.config.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are building a Web API, that wants to call an SOAP endpoint.  You have imported the WSDL into APIM and when you call APIM from your ASP.NET Web API you are getting the error above back.  Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure if this the same issue that was also reported on MSDN forums but there currently is a bug with APIM Soap Passthrough and using the subscription-key query parameter.  We are working on a fix currently.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should not use the subscription key for authentication.

I guess APIM will forward all headers by default. But if not, you can try something like this:

```
<set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="override">
    <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", ""))</value>
</set-header>
```

Comment: I think the problem is they are trying to figure out how to send the "ocp-blah" header from the client.  Setting HTTP headers in SOAP client frameworks is not always obvious.

Comment: That's also true. I created a post in the APIM forum for that a couple days ago: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4a175553-7a3b-4194-bb8d-5bc465fc7546/soap-configuration-with-subscriptionkey-in-url?forum=azureapimgmt&prof=required

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  That was my fault.  I reviewed the fix yesterday.  It should start to roll out next week.

Comment: thank you for all answers. I actually found mid way while calling APIM soap end point I am also adding subscrition key in Dot net solution. I have added web api using web reference. and in reference.cs I have passed header(subscription key of Soap APIM).It worked :)